# Eclipse - When I create a JUnit Suite, the list of test classes is empty. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a package with 4 test classes.  I want to make a JUnit Test Suite.  So in Eclipse, I right click my package and do `New > Other > JUnit Test Suite`

The wizard has a warning that, **"Warning: No test classes selected"** and the list of `Test Classes to include in suite:` is empty.

I'm not sure why.  I have several *Test.java classes with `public` methods annotated with `@Test`.  I created these through the `JUnit Test Case` wizard...

I saw some code on other Stack Overflow answers that I could use to create a Test Suite, but why isn't it working in the IDE?

Should I even bother with a Test Suite?  It seems like I can just right click the package and `Run As > JUnit Test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you select the right package in the `New -> Other > JUnit Test Suite` menu ? By selecting a package with the "Browse..." button, you should see your test classes.

You can run all the tests directly with `Run As > JUnit Test` on the project but if you have many test classes it is recommended to use a Test Suite to regroup them (ex: slower tests, tests for a certain part of the program, etc.).

Take a look at [this post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0) to learn more about JUnit tests grouping.

Comment: I started by right clicking my package, so the `Source Folder` and `Package` are already filled in with correct values.  The Suite `Name` is **AllTests**.

Comment: Did you select the right JUnit version then ? You can switch between JUnit3 and 4 with the radio buttons. Also, did you make sure you had the JUnit library in your build path (I guess so since you created methods with the @Test annotation... !)

Comment: my JUnit Test Cases are Junit 4.  The wizard does not give an option for JUnit Test Suites.  `JUnit 4` is in my `Java Build Path`.

Comment: Sounds like an Eclipse bug... Everything looks alright to me... tell me if you have any more info that could help us find the cause of the problem!

Comment: You might be right.  I just created a brand new project, new class, new Junit test, and had the same problem creating a Suite.  FYI I have `Eclipse Platform Version: 3.6.3.r362_v20110302` on Red Hat 6.3.

Comment: On eclispe luna (4.4), what I discovered is that the (at)runwith and (at)suiteclasses will only work for classes that are contained within the same package as the suite class. annoying-

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, don't bother with Suites.

You can select the project and run it as a junit test.  Eclipse will find all the tests and run them

Comment: Not sure I agree with this. I have many packages of test cases, and selecting each one would be time consuming, and defeat the purpose clicking once to run a test suite. Now I could put ALL test packages into another package, but that change the architecture of my project.

Comment: Not the package, the project.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to me and the explanation is quite simple:
you've written your tests using **JUnit Jupiter**.

[image]

However, JUnit Test Suite Wizard let's you pick only **these 2 types** of suites: **JUnit3** or **JUnit4**.

[image]

Refactoring your tests to comply JUnit3 or JUnit4 will make them visible in JUnit Test Suite wizard.

Comment: So your saying Eclipse does not support auto-creating JUnit 5 test suites?

Answer (score 0):

Just group junit test cases using package. It is more reliable to check the counts of success and failure of each test cases.